# Scroll panel with HScrollBar Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I come here because I need some help. I have a panel and a HScrollBar and its Dock is Bottom. I want to know how to scroll horizontally using the HScrollBar in my panel.

Thanks.

I tried TranslateTransform with HScrollBar.Value for X and VScrollBar.Value for Y but with no success.
I tried AutoScrollPosition too.

Comment: `TranslateTransform` what? Something you're drawing? Can you share your current code? Are you using the a ScrollBar control for a specific reason (the *automatic* ones won't do)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScrollBar.Value`.

> Gets or sets a numeric value that represents the current position of
>   the scroll box on the scroll bar control.

Following your question:
You have a panel on a form that has a `HScrollBar`.
This code increments and decrements the position of the `HScrollBar`:

```
private void button_Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tick = 1;
    if (hScrollBar1.Value + tick <= hScrollBar1.Maximum)
        hScrollBar1.Value += tick;
}

private void button_Decrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tick = 1;
    if (hScrollBar1.Value - tick >= hScrollBar1.Minimum)
        hScrollBar1.Value -= tick;
}
```